# Increase carousel height in materialize css

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I have the following code snippet from my html template where I've used carousel from materialize css. The carousel is stuck with its default height of `400px`.
I tried to increase it's height via css:

```
.carousel{
        min-height: 550px;
 }
```

The above code does work on increasing the height of the slider. But when I change the screen resolution to mobile view some extra white space appears below the carousel pushing the contents below. Further more changing screen resolution back to desktop mode the slider height reaches 760px.

I would be very thankful if anyone could suggest a way to fix this issue.

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  fullWidth: true
});
```

```css
.carousel{
min-height:550px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">

  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?food" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?cat" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?corgi" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?retriver" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae explicabo odit inventore placeat, laboriosam qui expedita quibusdam, voluptas quia numquam provident nam rem quam hic eum repudiandae quisquam quod totam autem consequatur officiis possimus quasi iusto aut. Dignissimos eos recusandae veniam eius cupiditate consectetur suscipit explicabo tenetur tempore quod ea, at consequuntur sit laudantium qui minus laborum laboriosam quo in odit illum veritatis ducimus. Reiciendis modi quos, laborum aliquam autem quia soluta molestiae! Unde vero labore fuga numquam incidunt voluptates mollitia sit dolores possimus dolorum. Iusto aspernatur odit sint dolore. Magnam consequuntur perferendis expedita? Quidem inventore officiis alias, amet ex porro voluptatem sapiente quasi, sed vitae, aspernatur, odio nulla totam corrupti. Alias repellat, eligendi inventore rem, omnis laudantium nobis qui ab esse corrupti quibusdam ex porro debitis? Optio a modi quas esse neque autem natus consectetur, mollitia nostrum ut vel velit at ex, ipsam necessitatibus? Incidunt deserunt expedita commodi pariatur adipisci recusandae iusto, odio impedit magnam ipsum, ut earum quis a veritatis facere blanditiis magni est ullam unde. Quibusdam similique porro quae dolores quidem ipsa distinctio incidunt est enim, optio laboriosam maiores non itaque praesentium hic nam consequuntur a iste quas velit deserunt eum, possimus facere quasi. Soluta, incidunt cum.   

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set min-height:auto to .carousel class:

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  fullWidth: true
});
```

```css
.carousel {
  min-height: 550px
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .carousel {
    min-height: auto
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">

  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?food" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?cat" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?corgi" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/1024x512/?retriver" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae explicabo odit inventore placeat, laboriosam qui expedita quibusdam, voluptas quia numquam provident nam rem quam hic eum repudiandae quisquam quod totam autem consequatur officiis possimus
  quasi iusto aut. Dignissimos eos recusandae veniam eius cupiditate consectetur suscipit explicabo tenetur tempore quod ea, at consequuntur sit laudantium qui minus laborum laboriosam quo in odit illum veritatis ducimus. Reiciendis modi quos, laborum
  aliquam autem quia soluta molestiae! Unde vero labore fuga numquam incidunt voluptates mollitia sit dolores possimus dolorum. Iusto aspernatur odit sint dolore. Magnam consequuntur perferendis expedita? Quidem inventore officiis alias, amet ex porro
  voluptatem sapiente quasi, sed vitae, aspernatur, odio nulla totam corrupti. Alias repellat, eligendi inventore rem, omnis laudantium nobis qui ab esse corrupti quibusdam ex porro debitis? Optio a modi quas esse neque autem natus consectetur, mollitia
  nostrum ut vel velit at ex, ipsam necessitatibus? Incidunt deserunt expedita commodi pariatur adipisci recusandae iusto, odio impedit magnam ipsum, ut earum quis a veritatis facere blanditiis magni est ullam unde. Quibusdam similique porro quae dolores
  quidem ipsa distinctio incidunt est enim, optio laboriosam maiores non itaque praesentium hic nam consequuntur a iste quas velit deserunt eum, possimus facere quasi. Soluta, incidunt cum.

</div>
```

Comment: Thank your for your suggestion yet it didn't work out. Applying your suggestion **1.slider height remains 400px,**
**2. changing screen resolution back to desktop mode from mobile the slider height reaches 760px.**
**3.White space below slider in mobile view is removed**

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion yet it didn't work out. Applying your  suggestion 1. slider height will fix  2.  i want to both mobile mode as well desktop mode both height will be same, when it is desktop mode the height be increase but when i changed to mobile mode the height be decrease. plz give me some suggestion